# Historical data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

[ I have two tables TABLE5 & TABLE6

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE5 (NAME VARCHAR2(1), CKPY VARCHAR2(3), DT TIMESTAMP(3)); 

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘A’, ‘100’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘B’, ‘200’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘C', ‘300’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘D’, ‘400’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘E’, ‘600’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘F', ‘SKI’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘G’, ‘SKI’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘H’, ‘SKI’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-18 00:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO TABLE5 VALUES (‘I’, ‘500’, TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE6 (CKPY VARCHAR2(3), STS VARCHAR2(2));

INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('100','04');

INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('200','04');

INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('300','04');

INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('400','04');

INSERT INTO TABLE6 VALUES ('500','04');
```

I want to store the historical records in new table TABLE7(which has same table structure as TABLE5) and populate the records which are over 4 years old from now

We need to find out the records having STS of '04' and join table5 and table6 with CKPY common values and in addition to this, I need to select the TABLE5 records having CKPY value as 'SKI' which are over 4 years old from now...The query is

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE7(NAME VARCHAR2(1), CKPY VARCHAR2(3), DT TIMESTAMP(3)); 
  
  INSERT INTO TABLE7
  ( NAME, 
    CKPY, 
    DT 
  )
  SELECT T5.NAME,
         T5.CKPY,
         T5.DT
   FROM TABLE5 T5 JOIN TABLE6 T6 
   ON T5.CKPY = T6.CKPY
   WHERE T6.STS = '04'
   AND T5.DT < ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -48);
```

This is the query I have ran but I also need to populate the CKPY value of "SKI" which are over 4 year old as shown in picture.

I was not able to select the records having CKPY  'SKI' from table 5...What is the additional code I need to add][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00qeg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly.
You don't get any records for "SKI" because there are no entries for it in table 6. You can use a LEFT JOIN for this, like in the following example:

```
  SELECT T5.NAME,
         T5.CKPY,
         T5.DT
   FROM TABLE5 T5 LEFT JOIN TABLE6 T6 
   ON T5.CKPY = T6.CKPY AND T6.STS = '04'
   WHERE T5.DT < ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -48);
```

If you only want the records matching table 6 and all "SKI" from table5, you can add to this query:

```
AND (T6.CKPY IS NOT NULL OR T5.CKPY = 'SKI')
```

Comment: I have got extra record with CKPY '600'..that shouldn't be populated...First fetch the records having STS as '04'  with common CKPY value from both the tables which are over 4 year old and also I need to fetch the records having SKI value of CKPY column from table 5 which are over 4 year old

Comment: @Johnbsdk10 OK, I have added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort...I will come back to this comment if I face any issue...Thanks